# ругается на кодировку "Illegal mix of collations" при вызове процедуры в MySQL

Tags: mysql, база-данных

При попытке вызвать процедуру

```
CALL product_pagination(0, 5, 'Oткрытки')
```

мне выходит ошибка:

> Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='

вот код процедуры:

```
DELIMITER // 
CREATE PROCEDURE product_pagination (IN i INT, IN cout INT, IN categ CHAR) 
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM categories, products WHERE category_name = categ LIMIT i,cout
END//
```

Уточню, что кодировка во всех таблицах и полях utf8_unicode_ci

Answer (score 1):

сменил кодировку с utf8_unicode_ci на utf8_general_ci. Все заработало